# Laravel Dusk testing with sqlite drops file busy exception

Tags: sqlite, unit-testing, laravel-5.5, laravel-dusk

T try to write a laravel dusk login (with sqlite) test but I still kepp getting

```
 Tests\Browser\LoginTest::employee_can_login
ErrorException: unlink(/var/www/laravel/database/database.sqlite): Text file busy
```

my test looks like

```
   /** @test research analyst login **/
    public function employee_can_login()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create([
            'email' => 'login@gmail.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('password'),
        ]);

        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($user) {
            $browser->visit(new Login())
                ->type('email', 'login@gmail.com')
                ->type('password', 'password')
                ->press('Login')
                ->assertSee('Dashboard')
                ->assertSee('You are logged in!')
                ->assertSee($user->name);
        });
    }
```

on migration the sqlite tables were created,

What does that mean how do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

As answered in similar thread, this is common problem (at least for me) with virtual machines. You can try not to share this file (so probably better move this file to not shared directory) or to solve this temporary you need to restart your virtual machine to make it work.

Comment: trying the restart did not solved the problem, moving the file inside /home/database.sqlite I get on migrate ```PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 8 attempt to write a readonly database
```I tried to give permissions to the folder but does not work either

Comment: It should work without any problem, but maybe you should put this into other folder and (for example `/home/your-user`) and make sure you have 755 permissions for this file